# Looking for single word to represent "degree of completion"

Tags: single-word-requests, academia

I am writing a paper. There is a term used in my work that represents "the degree of completion", i.e., 32% in the phrase "32% was completed". I tried "progress" but think it's not intuitive and "completeness" but find this should be used to represent if an event is complete. This term is important for my work hence I want to find a single and intuitive word to represent its meaning, any suggestion?

Comment: What is the sentence you want to use the phrase in? Put a blank where you want the phrase to go. For example, if you were asking about your cat, one sentence could be "My cat is ____."

Comment: What I’ve seen is not a single word,  but “completion percentage” “completion level”  Also progress seems to fit- that’s what a progress bar shows.

Comment: @CJDennis "Our model can predict ___ (degree of completion) of action for video frame according to the image content in that frame". This is just an example. The main reason looking for a single word is that I want to use it in the paper title.

Comment: @Jim Thanks, both are great. I may give up looking for a single word. Currently, I am using "progression", e.g. using "action progreesion" to represent the percentage of action progress has been done. I am also considering using the "progress rate". Any comments on these two? Thank you!

Comment: I think *progression* is fine if you are predicting ***what comes next***.  If you are predicting some level of completeness- a percentage, then I think *progression* is not the right word.  I also think progress rate is closer to the first derivative of *progress* and should not be used to label a completion percentage,

Comment: You need to edit your question with the extra information you put in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

"Completion" itself works for what you need, see for example:

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22percent+completion%22

Any phrase composed of "(fraction/percent) completion" will be understood to mean the degree of completion.

In the example sentence you provided it would be simply:

> "Our model can predict 30% completion of action for video frame according to the image content in that frame"

though the rest of that sentence could use some editing and I'm not sure what exactly you intend to convey.

Comment: But OP is asking for 'The degree of completion was 30%' say, and a bare 'completion' is unidiomatic here. The examples you link to are not of the required form, using '30% completion' say.

Comment: @Edwin "30% completion" is idiomatic.

Comment: Yes (and these are used in your linked examples). But not 'the completion was 30%'.

Comment: @Edwin I'm not sure why you are changing words around to make it fail.

Comment: OP asks for '... a term  ... that represents "the degree of completion", i.e., 32% in the phrase "32% was completed". ' It's _you_ who are changing words around. And the title requests  '[A] single word to represent “degree of completion" '; if the answer were merely 'completion', the correct response would be to C-V rather than answer, on 'more suitable for ELL' or 'lack of research shown' grounds.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth See their sample phrase in the comments.

Comment: That's not part of the question (and perhaps conflicts with the question).  << "the degree of completion? 32%" >> // << "the XXXX? 32%" >> //BUT < "the completion? 32%" >>  _Incorrect_.

Comment: @Edwin Ok, I look forward to your answer that correctly covers what you think the question is, then.

Comment: I don't believe there is one. In such cases, I don't answer.